# SQL query include latest date in count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sample where I am counting the number of records and displaying them as `CustomerIDCount`. I would also like to include the `LatestDate` but I am not sure if I need another query or I can add it to this one?

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a4acd6/1)

Setup

```sql
CREATE TABLE log
(
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL, 
    [LogDate] [datetime] NULL
);
    
INSERT INTO log ([CustomerID], [LogDate])
VALUES
    (1, 2021-02-12),
    (2, 2021-02-12),
    (1, 2021-02-12),
    (3, 2021-03-12),
    (4, 2021-02-12)
;
```

My attempt:

```sql
SELECT
    CustomerID, COUNT(*) CustomerIDCount
FROM
    (SELECT  CustomerID
     FROM log) g
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
ORDER BY 
    CustomerIDCount
```

Results:

| CustomerID | CustomerIDCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

But my desired results would be:

| CustomerID | CustomerIDCount | LatestDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-02-12 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-03-12 |
| 4 | 1 | 2021-02-12 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-03-12 |

Comment: Is "latest" simply the MAX value of that column for a given ID or is it the value from the "last" row for a given ID (and how do know which row is last)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a sub-query, and you can just add Max(LogDate) to the query.

```
select CustomerID, count(*) CustomerIDCount, max(LogDate) as max_LogDate
from log
group by CustomerID
order by CustomerIDCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from this limited information, and am assuming you have a Group By on customer ID, with a COUNT. Can you just add MAX(LatestDate) to that query?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT CustomerID
     , Count(*) AS CustomerIDCount
     , Max(LogDate) AS LastestDate
FROM   log
GROUP
    BY CustomerID
;
```